# Is it possible to use non user created labels in gmail with google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Goal: Auto delete emails in the gmail promotions tab after a set time.

Current knowledge: I know it is possible to use user created labels with google script. However, I want to use "Promotions" the tab as a label. Or barring that, "Important" as a label.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not be a problem, you will be able to query GMailApp and get the threads, so that you can delete them based on timestamp.

```
var threads = GmailApp.search('category:promotions before:2011/10/01');
```

If you want to get email from your 'Important' label, you will need to get the threads using

```
var threads = GmailApp.search('label:important before:2011/10/01');
```

A word of caution, only the first 500 threads will be returned.

Let me know if you need more guidance.

Comment: THX! Nice way to play with it.

Answer (score 0):

How about a small test script to handle the 500 threads limit ?

```
function testmail(){
  for(var start = 1 ;start < 2000 ; start=start+500){ // 2000 is an example, depending on the number of threads you can hit th logger limit quite easily...
    var threads = GmailApp.search('category:promotions before:2013/08/01', start, 500)
    for(var n in threads){
      var tnr = Number(start)+Number(n)
      Logger.log('threads n° '+tnr+' = '+threads[n].getFirstMessageSubject()+' has '+threads[n].getMessageCount()+' messages ending on '+threads[n].getLastMessageDate());
    }
  }
}
```

note : please choose [patt0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2748922/patt0)'s post as first answer.